# Should I take the job offer or negotiate with my current employer?

Tags: job-offer, job-change

After working at my current company for 2 years, i have asked for an increment of 40% ( i joined as a fresh graduate with a VERY low salary as a start). I spoke with the finance manger (who is responsible about the salary increments and is also my direct manager since they didn’t hire a manager for my department) and he didn’t tell me yes or no about the percentage and just said “ i will give you based on what i can”  and i waited after that for 2 months then was disappointed with increment of 20% .

I felt very under appreciated back then and started looking other options. One place have replied to me and want to give offer.
The offer is 25% more than what I’m taking now and there’s a good career growth with it.

Before going to get the offer i spoke with the finance manager again , told him that I’m not satisfied with the increment i got and the number I’m getting is less than the effort I'm putting and it’s below the market value ( i did my research and found the average value for my position at my country) and i have proved myself within the 2 years and I want my salary to be within the market value. Explained to him my tasks and how i improved during the 2 years.

He told me that my work is good and i have improved and i deserves the number I’m asking but this is the maximum he can give now. He said Just prove yourself within the coming months and i will give you a senior role promotion with increment and we are investing on you.

He didn’t specify timeframe or salary range and told me the promotion might be end of year or maybe before. He Didn’t specify anything

My problem is I’m worried I’ll wait till end of year and the increment might be below what i want. Knowing that the company CAN give me the number that i asked now since they took a very big investment and are paying on hiring new people/ huge marketing /etc.

Comparing the two options:

My current company:

The company name where I’m working now is growing and they are willing to expand their services/open more branches and go next level. I’m the only one in my department and any hiring after will be someone less than my experience ( i will be leading the team) . They are good with me and want me to stay. But my concern is the pay which is really low compared to the market and they didn’t hire a manager to train me so I’m just teaching myself by myself which i feel might affect my career development.

The new company:

I will be working with a team and there’s a manager for the department which I believe is better for me to learn since at my current role i didn’t work with a manager or leader and only teaching myself. Second, the pay they are offering me is good

Comment: Keep in mind that once you let go of your new job offer, you lose all negotiation leverage.

Comment: There are a zillion articles out there that explain why it's a bad idea. Here's just one: https://www.apollotechnical.com/reasons-to-not-accept-a-counteroffer/ The big question I have for you is: Is the money the only reason you want to leave?

Answer (score 19):

Just take the higher offer and resign your current position.  In my experience "negotiating" a higher salary when you have a competitive offer rarely works well especially in the long term.  Currently your company pays you what they think you're worth to them.  If you force their hand you end up only borrowing against your future there.

Sometimes it's a lot better just to go where what you bring is more appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "borrowing against your future" in the first paragraph?

Comment: I mean you get a raise today at the expense of future pay raises down the road.

Comment: Studies show that companies "matching a competing offer" rarely ends in good outcomes for the EE or the ER. I wholeheartedly recommend taking the new offer and rejecting any attempts to bribe you back to an organization that is not a mutual fit. Let them find the person that does fit what they have to offer while you find the ER that fits you.

Answer (score 9):

Take the new job. Do not entertain nor accept a counteroffer.

Actually you doomed yourself to this job change when you accepted the sub-par salary two years ago. You would be amazed at how difficult it is for a company to raise your compensation to current market rates when they are already getting you for cheap. Even if they really like you.

You have already suffered one substantial disappointment. How many more are you going to stick around for? Go.

Answer (score 1):

> I spoke with the finance manger (who is responsible about the salary increments and is also my direct manager since they didn’t hire a manager for my department)

If the person in charge of your salary and professional growth is in a dramatically different professional field, it's time to correct this and look elsewhere. How can they possibly understand the value you represent? How will they grow you professionally?

> I’m just teaching myself by myself which i feel might affect my career development.

This confirms my fears. I've been in a similar situation, and while I valued the freedom and flexibility to experiment on my own, more than a few months was too long. I lost many mentorship opportunities by letting myself be the wisest person on my team, professionally speaking. Over a decade later, I am still paying the price in some ways.

A happy accident of being properly placed in a well-functioning organization is that they are likely successful enough to pay you well to boot. Even if that weren't the case, a lateral move financially that gets you onto a better team will set you up for much more lucrative opportunities in the future. But as you're describing, you get both with this new role.

In short, this is a no-brainer. Take the new job.