# Employee name removed from the organization chart

Tags: salary, united-states, canada, tech-industry, technology

I recently noticed something weird. I have been working in a company as an R&D researcher since 2019.  I have been part-time during my studies as a master's student and then got hired as a full-time employee afterward. I am an engineer and EIT member, but the company assigned a non-engineering title for my position and a junior name. They have not even changed over the years that I have been with them.

I recently noticed that my name is not included in the new organization chart. Basically, they removed my name from the organizational chart. My research paper and work got published as a patent in some other competitive company without them taking an action against that. There is a recent management change in the company, and the new management does not even know what I have done or am doing. No one is following those patent things right now.

My name is still on the employee page but got removed from the organization chart.  This made me sad.

Do all those mean that they do not value my work and do not want me to be part of them?

I assume it is meaningful when your name has been removed from the organization chart.

I recently got a job offer from some other company. Do you think it is a good idea to negotiate with these people to stay? If so, how? Or do I need to move?

**Please note that:** there is no new manager coming from outside; it is just a manager coming from other department and taking over the power. The person has been in the company for the past 10-15 years.  They fired my old manager and some other people; that is why I assume those.

Comment: have you asked the people who made the chart? And is your company large enough that you might not know them personally?

Comment: The company is around 150-200 people, it is not a big company. They know me personally by my name, even CEO and the  manager, they just do not know what I worked on.

Comment: "*Do all those mean that they do not value my work*": how are we supposed to know what they think? As the last paragraph of questions, they're mostly opinion-based. It's up to you to decide what's best for your sake and future, don't you think?

Comment: How can IT remove your name from organization chart? They usually get the chart from managers. I do not believe it is an accident. Plus we are only 3 people working on this project, so how they did not remove my colleague.

Comment: "*how they did not remove my colleague?*": you're asking us to guess why a company did something, how would we know?

Comment: @OldPadawan, thank you. I want to see if someone was in the same situation or not.

Comment: If you want to know what they are thinking, ask them. I think you're overreacting badly, but that can only be a guess.

Comment: **there is no new manager coming from outside, it is just a manager coming from other department"* So actually there is a new manager coming from outside. Outside the department, but still, it is outside for what matters to your day by day ...

Answer (score 7):

Firstly:

> I assume it is meaningful when your name has got removed from the organization chart.

Without being too corny: when you assume, you make an **ASS** out of **U** and **ME**.

Secondly, apply [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor):

> never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity

Or in summary: stop assuming, go and talk to your manager already and ask what's going on.

Comment: OK, I have this job offer, I do not want to get in an argument with them, how do you think I approach the management? I was thinking that I tell them I have job offer, I will stay if you try to match, otherwise I am leaving. I will work for you as part time if you are interested. They fired my old manager and some other people that is why I assume those.

Comment: I can only echo what OldPadawan has already said to you: "It's up to you to decide what's best for your sake and future"

Comment: @Happypumpkinpm  Beware counteroffers!!!  There's lots of advice in questions like this:  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/183532/should-i-take-the-job-offer-or-negotiate-with-my-current-employer

Comment: *I was thinking that I tell them I have job offer, I will stay if you try to match, otherwise I am leaving. I will work for you as part time if you are interested.*
You do not force counteroffer. Counteroffer may or may not come from them. If you say things so bluntly, you can be almost sure that they will say "we do this or you leave? there is the door, bye".
With the part time offer you are even worse, you are asking them "I leave or I can work part-time for you" which will trigger the same response "you can leave, no worry".

Answer (score 6):

We have no way to determine if dropping you from the org-chart was a mistake or an intentional move and if so what the intention is.

Right now, this is a "you" problem. *You* have a problem with it. And since you are at the bottom of the totem pole, it will be handled with... reluctance at best.

Move it up the ladder. Go to your manager and tell them "Hey, I noticed the new org chart, it seems I am no longer reporting to you. Isn't that weird? Is that a mistake?"

And watch how fast mistakes get corrected when requested by someone higher up.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, since you moved from part to full time recently, you were taken off the former list and added to the latter, but someone was working from an outdated copy of the full-time list.

Yes, I'd say point it out to your manager. But it may be a while before the next official org chart is released, so once reported you should just trust that it will eventually get corrected.

Job titles etc. are company policy decisions and we can't do much about them -- but, again, your manager may be able to. On the other hand, realistically, you are a new hire and that may mean you have to accept a lower title and less authority until you can be promoted -- so work with your manager on how quickly you can get promoted. But seriously, outside academia and the military nobody much cares what your official title is; the question is what tasks you're doing and how much support you get from your management chain.